# Problem detected: Apache Not Found !, Disabling Apache buttons

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I have been using xampp for a long time, everything was fine and work correctly.

one month ago the xampp server shut down suddenly and when try to start the apache I couldn't, it shows that start button disabled and I cant start it.
it gave me an error:

```
Problem detected: Apache Not Found!
8:16:51 PM  [Apache]    Disabling Apache buttons
8:16:51 PM  [Apache]    Run this program from your XAMPP root directory!
8:16:51 PM  [mysql]     Problem detected: MySQL Not Found!
8:16:51 PM  [mysql]     Disabling MySQL buttons
8:16:51 PM  [mysql]     Run this program from your XAMPP root directory!
```

I have tried all solutions:

1. I tried to re-install again but still same problem.
2. I disabled UAC while sitting up the xampp.
3. I disabled anti-virus on the laptop.
4. I changed the port number in the config file.
5. I installed the last version and the old version.

after many tries, I found out that when I start the Apache and MySQL it gives me unexpected error then it shut down and it deletes the following files from xampp folder in C:
`mysql.exe` and `httpd.exe` 
that is why the buttons are disabled.
I did backup for these two files so and copied them and past them back in their specific paths and this what happened:

```
8:22:56 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
8:22:56 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:22:56 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:22:56 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:22:56 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:22:56 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
8:22:56 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

After that, these two files deleted again ...!!

I really have no idea how to fix this I did search everywhere but nothing worked with me.
I hope someone leads me with a proper solution for this issue I will be thankful for that.